# Read all lines in file and execute in a random order

Tags: python, python-2.7

I would like to create a python script that reads an input file in a random order rather than sequentially while running through a loop, so each time the script runs it would always run in a random order.

Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, you can do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the input file is not too big you can:

```
from random import shuffle

file_handle = open("my_file")
lines = file_handle.readlines()

shuffle(lines)

for i in lines:
     # You get random lines
```

Answer (score 1):

This is certainly possible. I'd use `File.readlines` to get the lines of the file and then shuffle it in-place with `random.shuffle`. Your script might look something like

```
import random as r
lines = file("/path/to/input/file", 'r').readlines()
r.shuffle(lines)

#Proceed with script
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a random number loop that

1. Generates a random number between 1 and however many lines of code your file is
2. Checks if that random number has already been generated.

   2.1. If it hasn't, do that line of code

   2.2 If it has, don't do anything

Also have a count of how many lines of code has been outputted, so when that equals the file's lines of code, you know to stop looping.